# How to close first modal befor navigating third modal in ionic 2

Tags: typescript, ionic2

In `OrderListModal` page when `OrderDetailModal` opens and order accepted I want to go third modal "`DeliveryProcessModal`" but in same time two previous modals should be closed. second modal is easy to close but I don't know how to close first modal in navigating process.

Comment: Can you explain properly with your requirement?

Comment: could you share your code how you currently maintain the order?

Comment: Dear friends, I solved by using onDidDismiss() method

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the [popToRoot](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#popToRoot) method.

According to Ionic API docs:

> Navigate back to the root of the stack, no matter how far back that
>   is.

Use poptoRoot which returns a promise, then push your `DeliveryProcessModal`.

```
this.navCtrl.popToRoot().then(() => {
//Present your modal
});
```